# How to convert a list into multiple arguments in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, arraylist, arguments

For example,

```
var listToBecomeArguments = ["foo","bla"];

myFunc(listToBecomeArguments);
```

when called would do something like this:

```
function myFunc(arg1, arg2) {
    // arg1 is "foo", arg2 is "bla"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your function

```
function myFunc(arg1, arg2) {...}
```

use the [.apply() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) like this:

```
myFunc.apply(null, listToBecomeArguments);
```

and it will do the same as this:

```
myFunc(listToBecomeArguments[0], listToBecomeArguments[1],...);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use  local variable [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) to do what you want.

```
function myFunc() {
 console.log(arguments);
}

myFunc("param1", "param2");

// Output:
// > ["param1","param2"]
```

Quoting the MDN article above, `arguments` is

> an Array-like object corresponding to the arguments passed to a function.